# Facebook Messenger "Get Started" button not sending the user defined payload

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, payload, facebook-messenger-bot

I have setup a "get started" button on my page:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ 
  "get_started":{
    "payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"
  }
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=token"
```

This works fine and responds with `{"result":"success"}`

If I check the data:

```
curl -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?fields=get_started&access_token=token
```

I've got a good answer: `{"data":[{"get_started":{"payload":"GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD"}}]}`

**However** when I receive the postback webhook, I've got this payload:

```
{
  "object": "page",
  "entry": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "time": 1501688073860,
      "standby": [
        {
          "recipient": {
            "id": "id1"
          },
          "timestamp": 1501688073860,
          "sender": {
            "id": "id2"
          },
          "postback": {
            "title": "Get Started"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

There is now way I can get the payload I defined (`GET_STARTED_PAYLOAD`) in the webhook.

On [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback) the doc says

> payload parameter that was defined with the button. This is only visible to the app that send the original template message.

This message is kind of confusing. Any ideas ?

Comment: Make sure you did not use wrong access token to create get started button. It seems to me like the last webhook you are gettting is subscribed to FB page that does not have same access token as access token used to create button.

Comment: Are you using the handover protocol? One condition that would cause this is if the app doesn't currently have thread control, which is denoted by the event being receiving in the `standby` channel.

Comment: Yes I opened a ticket on facebook dev and that was the conclusion. Thank you @amuramoto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting this answer here in case anyone needs it.

The `standby` prop indicates you're using the handover protocol, and that the app doesn't have thread control. This causes you not to receive the expected postback event, since the receiving app is not the same as the app that sent the postback.